# Prove $\frac{a}{bc}+ \frac{b}{ca}+ \frac{c}{ab} \ge 1$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $\dfrac{1}{bc}+ \dfrac{1}{ca}+ \dfrac{1}{ab} \ge 1$. Prove that $\dfrac{a}{bc}+ \dfrac{b}{ca}+ \dfrac{c}{ab} \ge 1$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Thank you, I will remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $X=\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{ca}+\frac{1}{ab}$ and $Y=\frac{a}{bc}+\frac{b}{ca}+\frac{c}{ab}$. In fact, if $X\ge 1$, then $Y\ge \sqrt{3}$. ($\sqrt{3}$ is optimal, because when $a=b=c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, $X=1$ and $Y=\sqrt{3}$.)

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,

$$3(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge (a+b+c)^2.$$

It follows that

$$Y=\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{abc}\ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3abc}=\frac{abc}{3}  X^2\ge \frac{abc}{3}.$$

If $abc\ge 3\sqrt{3}$, we are done. Otherwise, by inequality of arithmetic and geometric means,

$$Y\ge 3(abc)^{-\frac{1}{3}}\ge \sqrt{3}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Remember, that for any nonzero $x$, one has

$$
x+\frac{1}{x} \geq 2 \tag{1}
$$

We apply this inequality repeatedly. Put

$$
T=\dfrac{a}{bc}+ \dfrac{b}{ca}+ \dfrac{c}{ab}
$$

We have 
$$
T=\frac{a^2+b^2}{abc}+\frac{c}{ab} =\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{ab} \bigg(\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{c}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
}\bigg) \geq \frac{2(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})}{ab},
$$

by using (1) with $x=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{c}$. Then,

$$
T \geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{ab}} \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}} \geq \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{ab}}
$$
by using (1) with $x=\frac{a}{b}$. So $T \geq \sqrt{\frac{8}{ab}}$.

We see that if $ab \leq 8$, we are done. So we may assume $ab \geq 8$. By symmetry, we may also assume
$ac \geq 8, bc \geq 8$. But then

$$
1 \leq \dfrac{1}{bc}+ \dfrac{1}{ca}+ \dfrac{1}{ab} \leq \frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8} =\frac{3}{8},
$$

which is impossible.

Comment: I think you forgot a $\sqrt$ in the line after the "We have", in the numerator of the first factor in the third expression from the left.

Comment: @user3533 : Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Very good answer. I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: How do you justify the fact that assuming $ab\geq 8$ allows to assume $bc\geq 8$ and $ca\geq 8$? If it's boring to type, I would appreciate onilne links instead.
P.S. it was not me who downvoted.

Comment: @Freddy : “symmetry” is the word.

Comment: @Freddy: If you take the proof that $ab \leq 8$ is enough and exchange $a$ and $c$ whenever they appear you will get a proof that $ca \leq 8$ is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I want to give a complete answer.

Assume by the sake of contradiction that $$\frac{a}{bc}+\frac{b}{ca}+\frac{c}{ab}<1.\tag{1}$$
By Cauchy Schwarz it follows from $(1)$ that $$\frac{3}{abc}>\frac{3}{abc}\left(\frac{a}{bc}+\frac{b}{ca}+\frac{c}{ab}\right)\geq \left(\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{ca}\right)^2.\tag{2}$$

From $(2)$ we recover two facts

- By $AM-GM$ mean $$\left(\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{ca}\right)^2\geq 3\left(\frac{1}{a^2bc}+\frac{1}{ab^2c}+\frac{1}{abc^2}\right),$$ therefore, combined with $(2)$, we obtain on one hand $$1>\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c},\tag{3}$$ which implies that $\min\{a,b,c\}>1$ (remember that they are all positive).
- On the other hand we can also derive from $(2)$ and $(3)$ the following: $$\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{ca}\right)}>\frac{a+b+c}{3}>1,\tag{4}$$

which in the end leads to an absurd with respect to the hypothesis of the problem.

Then $(1)$ must be false and the problem is solved.

Answer (score -3):

multiply abc

$a+b+c\geq abc $

$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq abc $

$a^2+b^2+c^2-(a+b+c)$

$⇔(a-\frac12)^2+(b-\frac12)^2+(c-\frac12)^2\geq \frac34$

therefore

$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq \frac34+abc$

Comment: @Did This is correct, though.